# php curl stop to get me result

Tags: php, curl

some know why curl stop to give me result after 12 pages ?

im using simple html dom , looking for answer everywhere

```
<pre><code>

include 'simple_html_dom.php';
for ($i=1;$i<20;$i++)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?site=glo&g=y&SearchText=baby+romper&page=$i&initiative_id=SB_20151130033753&shipCountry=IL&needQuery=n");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.test.com");
$html = str_get_html(curl_exec($ch));


foreach($html->find('a[class=product]') as $a)
{

    echo  $a->attr['href']."<br/>";

}
echo "<h1>$i</h1>";
}
curl_close($ch);
</code></pre>
```

Comment: Are you running script on your local PC ? if yes then are you able to open the url in your browser?

Comment: SOMEONE can help me ?

Comment: Don't bump the question, especially within 40 minutes after posting it. Give it some time (a day?) and expand the question with extra information you have gathered in the mean time (error logs, etc).